# How can I create an RSS feed from Salesforce activity?

Tags: chatter-feed

I'd like to create an RSS feed when certain Accounts are created and updated.  The end goal is exposing certain data elements on an external directory page in Wordpress.  Wordpress has many RSS plugins - but so far the only info I can find on this is in this 2010 blog post: http://techsahre.blogspot.ca/2010/03/rss-feed-power-with-salesforce.html ?  Any better / more native / simpler ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are exposing the feed to an external page (meaning it's public), the platform has support for generating atom feeds (similar to RSS).

See: http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/adding-a-feed-to-your-force-com-site